# MacBook Air warranty from Canada

Tags: macbook-pro

I am about to buy MacBook Air from Kuwait, and I wonder if I can purchase warranty from Canada since am living in Canada and am a student of a University there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the warranty on Apple products is generally international, however you should not that some types of AppleCare are not just warranties but also insurance and the insurance component may have additional restrictions.

In the case of the MacBook Air AppleCare this is not an insurance product so it is international in countries that Apple offers service within.